# Which properties of Pauli matrices can be derived and cannot be derived from their algebra (without explicit representation)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, representation-theory, lie-algebra

Usually, [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices)  $\{ \sigma^i \} ~(i = 1, 2, 3)$ are defined as
\begin{align}
\sigma^1=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix},~
\sigma^2=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -i \\
i & 0
\end{pmatrix},~
\sigma^3=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}

These obey the following well-known algebra:
\begin{align}
 [\sigma^i, \sigma^j] &= 2i \sum_k \epsilon^{ijk} \sigma^k, \\
 \{\sigma^i, \sigma^j \} &= 2 \delta^{ij} {\bf 1}.
\end{align}

Then, which properties of Pauli matrices can be derived and cannot be derived only from their algebra (without explicit representation)?

Here I'd like to restrict them to $2\times2$ (complex-valued) matrices.

First, from 1st equation we can derive $\operatorname{Tr} \sigma^i = 0$.

However, how about their determinants?

From 2nd line, we see $(\det \sigma)^2 = 1$ but I don't know how we can find it to be $-1$ as we can calculate with their explicit representation.

Furthermore, there are lots of identities of them. For example, for $\sigma^\mu = (1, \sigma^i), \bar{\sigma}^{\mu} = (1, -\sigma^i)$,
\begin{align}
(\sigma^\mu)_{\alpha \dot{\alpha}} (\bar{\sigma}_\mu)^{\dot{\beta}\beta} = \delta^{\beta}_{\alpha}\delta^{\dot{\beta}}_{\dot{\alpha}}
\end{align}
holds (here I used dot notation).

I don't know how it is derived from above algebra.

So my question is: What are (famous) properties satisfied by Pauli matrices which are irrelevant to above algebra?

Comment: The *explicit* expression of the Pauli matrices are not consequence of the two relation you wrote. This is because those relations are invariant under the action of invertible  matrices $\sigma^k \to D \sigma^k D^{-1}$.

Comment: The last identity you wrote is not invariant under this sort of transformations and therefore is not a consequence of the only two identities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Pauli matrices are completely determined, up to a change of basis, by either the commutation relations or anti-commutation relations.   You only need one or the other.

For the case of commutation relations, you are asking for representations of $su(2)$, and such representations on $\mathbb{C}^2$ are unique up to change of basis.  The proof involves the highest weight method.

For the case of anti-commutation relations, you are asking for reprentations of a particular Clifford algebra, or equivalently here the "canonical anti-commutation relations" (CAR), and again such representations on $\mathbb{C}^2$ are unique up to change of basis.

I'll sketch the proof of uniqueness using the anti-commutation relations, since it's not usually written where the claim is made. To start, assume some representation.  We will change basis until the Paulis take their conventional form.  Put $\sigma_3$ in Jordan normal form; because it squares to the identity, it must be diagonalizable, with eigenvalues in $\{-1,1\}$. It cannot be the identity (otherwise it would not anti-commute with the others), so it must have eigenvalues $\pm 1$.  Change basis so that it is diagonal; now $\sigma_3$ takes its conventional form.  Then  using $\{\sigma_3, \sigma_1\}=0$, we know $\sigma_1$ must have zero diagonal and non-zero off-diagonal. You can change basis using a diagonal matrix so that $\sigma_1$ takes its conventional form. Finally, $\sigma_2$ must also have zero diagonal, and further inspection guarantees it is already in conventional form.

Answer (score 0):

[Due diligence first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices).

Tracing the commutator gives you tracelessness.

For traceless 2x2 matrices *m*, the -1 determinant is a trivial consequence of the [C-H theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem#Determinant_and_inverse_matrix), since

det =−<sup>2</sup>=−,

given the anticommutator specified.

You now have their two eigenvalues, $\pm 1$.

The way you have written the commutator, they have to be hermitian.

You may take any equivalently related form of the standard orthogonal basis set, and practitioners do.

Finally, review the stock [proof of completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Completeness_relation) predicated on your orthogonal basis given by the anticommutators.

Comment: They need not be Hermitian, right? The relations are invariant under similarity transformation, including conjugation by invertible but non-unitary operators, which wouldn't preserve Hermiticity.

Comment: As long as $S\sigma_i S^{-1}= \sigma_i^\dagger$. The algebra is invariant under hermiticity.